# Why won't this background music stop when I tell it to?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Coding a game for iOS 7, and I set it up so the music plays continuously. I've also set it up so that when the player is dead, to stop the music, but it continues to run the music until the clip of music is done. (To clarify, the clip is 7 seconds long, and for example, if the music is done at 0:03, it will continue into the next scene, until it hits 7)

Here's the code:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"bgmusic.m4a" waitForCompletion:YES]]];
if (_dead == YES) 
       [self removeAllActions];
}
```

I want the music to stop the second the player dies, as opposed to finishing the action. How can I code it so it does so? I had assumed that `[self removeAllActions];` would have done that? Is there a specific thing I can call to stop it instantaneously?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing the waitForCompletion: parameter to NO?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work because of the repeatActionForever @0x7fffffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code (AVAudioPlayer)...

```
NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"warmovie" withExtension:@"caf"];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

To stop...

```
[self.backgroundMusicPlayer stop]
```